# Domain change regex by file type for cdn integration

Tags: php, regex, cdn

I'm hoping for some help writing with a clean regex in PHP to convert the domain of certain kinds of assets from a string potentially containing urls of multiple assets (images, javascripts etc.)

For example:

```
$string = 'Some content including image tags <img src="http://domain.com/image.png" /> and image urls http://domain.com/image.png and javascript links <script src="http://domain.com/funtimes.js"></script> and js urls http://domain.com/funtimes.js but not this image http://notthisdomain.com/nope.png';
```

The regex should change the domain for assets at http://domain.com to http://cdndomain.com, but only for files with the extensions: .png .jpg .gif .js .css

The desired output for the above would be

```
$string = 'Some content including image tags <img src="http://cdndomain.com/image.png" /> and image urls http://cdndomain.com/image.png and javascript links <script src="http://cdndomain.com/funtimes.js"></script> and js urls http://cdndomain.com/funtimes.js but not this image http://notthisdomain.com/nope.png';
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
(?:http:\/\/domain.com)(\S*?\.(?:png|jpg|gif|js|css))\b
```

with

```
http://cdndomain.com\1
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/vJ2wK7/1)

---

The idea is to match your domain, followed by multiple characters, followed by one of the extensions. Replace that with the new domain and the remainder of the string captured in group 1.

---

Three important things to note here:

- `\S*` (multiple non-space characters) is used for matching the rest of this url. It is important not to use `.*` or `["']*` or something like that as if you get a fail match, and later there is another file with that extension the in between string will be included in the match.
- It is made lazy with `?` so that we also don't get in between matches.
- There is word boundary (`\b`) at the end so that a word that just has the characters `js` in it (for example) wont end the match and this is the actual extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'Some content including image tags <img src="http://domain.com/image.png" /> and image urls http://domain.com/image.png and javascript links <script src="http://domain.com/funtimes.js"></script> and js urls http://domain.com/funtimes.js but not this image http://notthisdomain.com/nope.png';
$file_types = "png|js|jpeg|jpg";

echo preg_replace ( "/http:\/\/domain.com([^\"']*($file_types))[\"']/" , "http://cdn.domain.com$1" , $string);

# output:
# Some content including image tags <img src="http://cdn.domain.com/image.png" /> and image urls http://cdn.domain.com/image.png and javascript links <script src="http://cdn.domain.com/funtimes.js"></script> and js urls http://cdn.domain.com/funtimes.js but not this image http://notthisdomain.com/nope.png
```

The way it works is it starts by matching http://domain.com. Then it keeps searching until it finds one of your defined `$file_types` extensions which much be followed immediately by a double quote or a single quote (`[\"']`).

If at any time during this search for an extension it hits a single quote or double quote first (`[^\"']`), we can infer this URL we are currently looking at does not have the extension we are looking for, and so we restart our search at the next URL.